# How to Combine Date and Time in LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Using Linq to SQL, I want to first combine these two fields: `DateEnter` (`Date?` type) and `TimeEnter` (`Integer?` type). Sort them by descending mode. Include the combined `DateEnter` and `TimeEnter` into one field of select.

I keep getting method not supported to translate sql.

```
Dim query = From a In dataContext.Orders
            Join b In dataContext.OrderStatus On b.OrderName Equals a.Name
            Where b.Status = "Finished"
            Let UpdatedAt = b.DateEnter + TimeSpan.FromHours(b.TimeEnter)
            Order By UpdatedAt Descending
            Select New With {
                Key .LastUpdatedAt = UpdatedAt,
                Key .Name = a.Name,
                Key .Owner = a.OrderOwner}
```

Comment: Remember that LINQ is just syntactic sugar and it is the specific LINQ provider that does the heavy lifting. In the case of LINQ to SQL, your VB code needs to be translated into T-SQL to be executed against the database and `TimeSpan.FromHours` cannot be translated. Entity Framework has its own library that contains methods to do things like this. Not sure whether L2S has something similar but I think that you're going to have to do it mathematically.

Comment: What SQL Engine / Database provider?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim query = From a In dataContext.Orders
            Join b In dataContext.OrderStatus On b.OrderName Equals a.Name
            Where b.Status = "Finished"
            Order By b.DateEnter.Value.AddSeconds(b.TimeEnter) Descending
            Select New With {
                Key .LastUpdatedAt = b.DateEnter.Value.AddSeconds(b.TimeEnter)
                Key .Name = a.Name,
                Key .Owner = a.OrderOwner}
```

Was able to got it.